# Dropdown selection gets data from different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to connect a dropdown option (dropdown has the options A-F). When selecting A, I need to go get data from different worksheets that have the option A and get the cell values next to that column in VBA code. The images below show an example of what I mean. Week 1 has options A-F with columns of attendance and grade. In the weekly worksheet, I need the dropdown to be able to depend on the options A-F to go get the cell values next to the value chosen in the dropdown from the specified week.

current code is :`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D4")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("D3:D4")
        Case "A": Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Copy
                    Worksheets(3).Range("B3").Paste
    End Select
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

`
see images attached:
[image: week1]
[image: week2]
[image: weekly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of these, in cell B3, and then copy it across and down:

```
=VLOOKUP($D3, INDIRECT("week" & A3 & "!$A:$C"), Column(), FALSE)

=VLOOKUP($D3, CHOOSE(A3, week1!$A:$C, week2!$A:$C), Column(), FALSE)
```

[The `INDIRECT` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) will parse a text string into a Cell Reference, while [the `CHOOSE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) will allow you to pick between different cell references to use, based on an input number.

Using `CHOOSE` will be more computationally efficient, but it will also lead to longer formulae, and be harder to add more weeks; you will have to add the cell reference to the list in the formula for each week, while `INDIRECT` just requires you to add the worksheet with the correct name.